# Display a 1 px border on check around a checkbox and radio button image

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to display a 1 px border on selection of the radio button and checkbox.

I am using this code to do for a radio button class.

```
 label.option_radio_label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
       display:none;
       }
 label.option_radio_label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
       cursor:pointer;
       border:1px solid transparent;
       height: 100px; 
       }
label.option_radio_label > input:checked + img{ 
/* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
       border: 1px solid #000;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
       }
label.option_radio_label > input.c_disabled:checked + img{ 
/* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
      border: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      border-radius: 0px;
      }
```

here is my **_radio_option.html.erb** code

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 part_option_wrapper">
     <center>
       <% if pre_disabled %>
        <div class='option_overlay'></div>
      <% end %>
       <label for="order_part_<%= radio_option.part.id %>_option_<%=  radio_option.id %>" 
              class="option_radio_label">
       <%= radio_button_tag "order[part][#{radio_option.part.id}][option]", 
         radio_option.id, 
         radio_option.is_default?, 
         class: "radio_option #{pre_disabled ? 'c_disabled' : ''}",
         "data-option-part" => radio_option.part.id, 
         "data-option-name" => radio_option.name, 
         "data-option-disables" => "#{radio_option.disables.map(&:disable_element_id)}", 
         "data-option-subid" => "option_subid_#{radio_option.id}",
         "data-option-group" => "part_#{radio_option.part_id}", 
         "data-option-enables" => "#{radio_option.enables.map(&:enable_element_id)}", 
         disabled: (pre_disabled ? true : false) %>
    <%= image_tag radio_option.photo(:small), class:  "radio_option_img", 
         "data-option-part" => radio_option.part.id, 
         "data- option-name" => radio_option.name %>
       <br><%= radio_option.name %>
      </label>
     </center>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is **my _part_child.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-12 part-child-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <label><%= part_child.name %></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10 selected_part_child">
     <% if part_child.display_type == "dropdown" %>   
      <%= select_tag "order[part][#{part_child.parent.id}][children][][part][#{part_child.id}][option][][id]", 
         options_for_part_child(part_child), 
         class: "form-control child_option",  
         "data-option-subid" => part_child.id, 
         "data-option-name" =>  part_child.name %>
     <% elsif part_child.display_type == "radio" %>
      <div class="row">
       <%= options_radio_tag part_child %>
      </div>
     <% elsif part_child.display_type == "checkbox" %>
       <div class="row">
      <%= options_checkbox_tag part_child %>
      </div>
      <% elsif part_child.display_type == "textbox" %>
       <div class="row">
        <%= options_textfield_tag part_child %>
       </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

PS: inspect element for the **radio child** part

```
  <div class="col-sm-2">
   <label  for="order_part_11_children__part_14_option__id">
     <input  id="order_part_14_option_48" ,=""  class="radio_option_child" 
       data-option-name="Edge" data-option-id="14"  
       name="order[part][11][children][][part][14][option][][id]" 
       type="radio"  value="48" checked="" 
       data-option- subid="option_subid_48">
     <img  src="/system/options/photos/000/000/048/original/cuff_doublebutton.jpg? 1424078897">  Edge 
  </label>
 </div>
```

But when I try to do the same for the children's radio options and checkboxes, I am not able to get that working.

Please help.

Comment: Hi - it might help us if you show us a snippet of the html for the checkboxes too.

Comment: The CSS looks ok to me. Can you add the HTML generated for the radio along with the label?

Comment: @Suraj I wanted the actual HTML generated out of this code than the rails helper etc. If you can inspect the page and copy the elements here would be better for us to understand.

Comment: added that. Please check

Comment: In CSS you have `label.option_radio_label` while the snippet you have doesn't have class for label.

Comment: label is just a label and not a class and I am adding that class property to that label.

Comment: CSS wont be applied if `option_radio_label` is not added to the label. Since you have added the snippet generated with your code the label is not having a class. So ` label.option_radio_label > input` would never work. You will have to change that to `label > input`.

Comment: Or are you adding the class with JS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71848/discussion-between-suraj-and-anpsmn).

Answer (score 0):

In your radio button template, you have correctly add the class `class="option_radio_label"` to your label... but it's clearly not coming through in the html. The problem is not with your css.. but the fact that the class is not actually showing up in the final html.

That may be due to a typo, or some other interference - but that's where you need to concentrate your efforts.

Comment: `radio_option` template (as opposed to what's in the resulting html)

Comment: you are saying adding `class = "option_radio_label"` to **part_child** will do?

Where exactly that line will go to the main template of child??

Comment: Nope - I got that wrong and have updated my answer. double check for typos in the template where it's adding that class to the `label` or for javascript that is removing that class. Something is going wrong such that that class is not appearing in the final html - and that's what you need to figure out and fix